# Merge for all "occurrences" of a non-key variable

Tags: r, merge, data.table, outer-join

I have two datasets, and what I want may be loosely termed as "outer join on a non-key variable".

Here are the datasets

Dataset 1

```
oc  oc2 state_id    r_state 
A011    A01 1808    1.00    
A011    A01 1810    0.50    
A012    A01 1810    0.50    
A011    A01 1814    0.33    
A012    A01 1814    0.33    
A013    A01 1814    0.33
```

Dataset 2

```
oc  r_country
A011    0.62
A012    0.14
A013    0.24
```

what I want as output is following:

```
oc  oc2 state_id    r_state r_country
A011    A01 1808    1.00    0.62
A012    A01 1808    NA      0.14
A013    A01 1808    NA      0.24
A011    A01 1810    0.50    0.62
A012    A01 1810    0.50    0.14
A013    A01 1810    NA      0.24
A011    A01 1814    0.33    0.62
A012    A01 1814    0.33    0.62
A013    A01 1814    0.33    0.24
```

Note how the row numbers 2, 3 and 6 has been introduced "artificially". My question is how to do this in R. If I merge by `oc`, `merge` function will not create these rows. If I merge by `oc2`, it will create unnecessary extra rows. Note that `oc2` is just a higher level coding of `oc`. Below are few lines of code to get the above datasets in data.tables. Note that these are sample datasets and actual data contain around 50 different `oc2` and each `oc2` can have 1 to 9 `oc` in it. Also, there are 47 different states.

```
DT1 = data.table(oc = c('A011','A011','A012','A011','A012','A013'),
                 oc2 = rep('A01',6),
                 state_id = c(1808,1810,1810,1814,1814,1814),
                 r_state = c(1, 0.5,0.5,0.33,0.33,0.33)
                )

DT2 = data.table(oc = c('A011','A012','A013'), 
                  r_country = c(0.62, 0.14, 0.24)
                )
```

Though I am using `data.table`, base `data.frame` solution will also do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using:

```
library(zoo) # for the 'na.locf'-function

DT1[CJ(oc = oc, state_id = state_id, unique = TRUE), on = .(oc, state_id)
    ][order(state_id), oc2 := na.locf(oc2), by = 'state_id'
      ][DT2, on = 'oc', r_country := r_country][order(state_id)]
```

gives:

> ```
>      oc oc2 state_id r_state r_country
> 1: A011 A01     1808    1.00      0.62
> 2: A012 A01     1808      NA      0.14
> 3: A013 A01     1808      NA      0.24
> 4: A011 A01     1810    0.50      0.62
> 5: A012 A01     1810    0.50      0.14
> 6: A013 A01     1810      NA      0.24
> 7: A011 A01     1814    0.33      0.62
> 8: A012 A01     1814    0.33      0.14
> 9: A013 A01     1814    0.33      0.24
> ```

Per @Frank's suggestion, you can also do it without using `na.locf` from the `zoo`-package:

```
DT1[CJ(oc = oc, state_id = state_id, unique = TRUE), on = .(oc, state_id)
    ][DT2, on = .(oc), r_country := i.r_country][DT1, on = .(state_id), oc2 := i.oc2][]
```

Comment: Thanks, you have implemented the "process" I was thinking in seconds. I never knew about `CJ` and `on`. Where do I read about them?

Comment: Also, `on = .(oc, state_id)` throw an error for me. I had to use  `on = c('oc', 'state_id')`. May be I have older version of `data.table`

Comment: @GauravSinghal I'm using version *1.10.4-3*; what version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I am using version *1.9.6*.

Comment: Zoo-less, this seems to work: `DT1[CJ(oc = oc, state_id = state_id, unique = TRUE), on=.(oc, state_id)][DT2, on=.(oc), r_country := i.r_country][DT1, on=.(oc), oc2 := i.oc2][]`?

Comment: @Frank Thx! Added with a minor change: I think the last join should be on `state_id`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be expressed as a single SQL statement using a triple join which joins together these 4 tables:

- `oc` which is formed from the unique `oc` values,
- `state_id` which is formed from the unique `state_id` values,
- `DT1` and
- `DT2`

using this code:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "
     with 
       oc as (select distinct oc from DT1),
       state_id as (select distinct state_id from DT1)

     select * 
       from oc
       join state_id
       left join DT1 using (oc, state_id)
       left join DT2 using (oc)
       order by state_id, oc"

sqldf(sql)
```

giving this output:

```
    oc state_id  oc2 r_state r_country
1 A011     1808  A01    1.00      0.62
2 A012     1808 <NA>      NA      0.14
3 A013     1808 <NA>      NA      0.24
4 A011     1810  A01    0.50      0.62
5 A012     1810  A01    0.50      0.14
6 A013     1810 <NA>      NA      0.24
7 A011     1814  A01    0.33      0.62
8 A012     1814  A01    0.33      0.14
9 A013     1814  A01    0.33      0.24
```